# What method is called first when storyboard loads?

Tags: initialization, xcode4.2, storyboard, segue

Using Xcode 4.2, in my application, a view loading is triggered by a segue event. **What method will be called first inside a view controller?**

`-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` works, but is it the first?

Initialization happens from the `Storyboard` it seems, `init` method is never manually called, upon object creation.

Let me clarify, when creating an instance of a class manually, we usually `[[alloc]init]` it first. `[init]` in this case, is the first method to be executed and a good place for various initializations.

What is the equivalent of `init` method when class instantiation happens via a segue event? In such a case, what method should contain all initialization logic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the best option is `-(void)awakeFromNib`. This only occurs the once, whereas `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` etc could be called more than once after your initialisation.

UPDATE: As pointed out by Jean-Denis Muys below, `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder` is a better option for an initialiser that only gets called once as `-(void)awakeFromNib` has the potential to be called more than once.

Comment: **-(void)awakeFromNib** never gets called when loading controller with segue. Does anybody have a better answer?

Comment: @DZenBot I think you're mistaken. I just double checked and -(void)awakeFromNib is being called on my UIViewController which is loaded with a segue.

Comment: except that `-(void)awakeFromNib` *can* be called several times (in some rather uncommon cases). The initializer that is called only once is `initFromCoder`

Comment: Yes, I have tested -(void)initFromCoder method, and it gets called all the time with no exception. -(void)awakeFromNib never got called when I perform a segue load. Odd isn't it?

Comment: I was not aware that `-(void)awakeFromNib` could be called multiple times. I guess that makes sense in the situation for when `viewDidLoad` gets called a second time. I've since started using `initFromCoder` as per your suggestion and that has been working like a charm too. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

According to Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW6),

> When you create a view controller in a storyboard, the attributes you
>   configure in Interface Builder are serialized in an archive. Later,
>   when the view controller is instantiated, this archive is loaded into
>   memory and processed. The result is a set of objects whose attributes
>   match those you set in Interface Builder. The archive is loaded by
>   calling the view controller’s `initWithCoder:` method. Then, the
>   `awakeFromNib` method is called on any object that implements that method. 
>   You use this method to perform any configuration steps that
>   require other objects to already be instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise not to use awakeFromNib. I use simply both of these functions

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupButton {
    /* get ready to be called twice */
    self.layer.cornerRadious = 10.0f;
}
```

**because:** let's say you subclassed UIButton. You must be ready for **two scenario**:

scenario 1. If you add the button programmatically --> initWithFrame->setupUI will be called
scenario 2. If you add the button using NIb --> initWithCoder->setupUI will be called.